# How can I stream an authenticated user's Google Drive audio file stored on xer Google Drive in my web app?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-api-javascript-client

How can I stream an authenticated user's private audio file stored on xer Google Drive in my web app?

Previously, I just gave a `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=[file ID]` link to the `<audio>` element, which while never *officially* recommended, worked for many years until Google just recently stopped letting people use it (consistently returns a 403: Forbidden error).

Now, I am trying to do it “properly”, but I don't see a way to.  If I use the `webContentLink` from `gapi.client.drive.files.get`, I also get a 403.  If I call it with `alt: 'media'`, I can get the file that way, but it seems to retrieve the entire file before I can do anything with it, which isn't ideal for streaming a large audio file.

Is there any way—ideally a “proper” way, but even any way at all at this point—to stream a user's audio file from xer Google Drive to an `<audio>` element?